# Issue while using Cherry-pick api using PRid

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, cherry-pick

I am trying to use the Git-Cherry API, in power shell to automate the process of cherry-picking a PR by its PRid.

```
$Body = @{
"generatedRefName" = "refs/test";
"ontoRefName" = $BranhcName;
"repository" = $RepoName;
"source" = $PRid #Prid is an integer value
}
#Cherr-Pick: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/cherry%20picks/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#gitasyncrefoperationsource
Invoke-WebRequest @req -Method POST -Uri "${baseuri}/git/repositories/${RepoName}/cherryPicks?${api}" -Body ($Body|ConvertTo-Json)
```

I get an issue as below when I try to cherry-pick this way,

> Invoke-WebRequest :
>   {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Exactly one source for a
>   cherry-pick must be 
>   specified.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitAsyncRefOperationInvalidSourceException,
>   Microsoft.TeamFo
>   undation.Git.Server","typeKey":"GitAsyncRefOperationInvalidSourceException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
>   At line:99 char:1
>   + Invoke-WebRequest @req -Method POST -Uri "${baseuri}/git/repositories ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebExce     ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

What is this error? - I am giving exactly one source as per my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The `repository` and `source` parameters in the request body are object type. But i see you assigned string and integer to them. See the rest api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/cherry%20picks/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body) (click the highlighted in below screenshot to check out details of the object type).

[image]

You should define `repository` and `source` as object type. See below example:

```
$Body = @{
"generatedRefName" = "refs/heads/dev-on-master";
"ontoRefName" = "refs/heads/master";
"repository" = @{
                  "name"= $RepoName
                };
"source" = @{
               "pullRequestId"= $PRid
             } 
}
```

Update:

I tested with below single commitId. It worked fine.

```
$Body= @{
"generatedRefName" = "refs/heads/commit-on-master";
"ontoRefName" = "refs/heads/master";
"repository" = @{
                  "name"= $RepoName
                };
"source" = @{
               "commitList"= @(
               @{
               "commitId" = "5cedf148826ed783786e5b9b6932cc07ec9d745e"
               }
               )
             } 
}
```

Above request body needs to be convert to json with deeper depth: `-Body ($Body|ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)`

`Invoke-WebRequest @req -Method POST -Uri "${baseuri}/git/repositories/${RepoName}/cherryPicks?${api}" -Body ($Body|ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)`

Comment: Yes, I checked that. The document says the Source accepts two types of input, in which on that accepts an integer value ( PrID) or a list of commitIDs. Only the list of commitIDs work with a limitation that if there is one commitid in the list it still fails with above issue.

Comment: Hi @TejaswiniN I tested with a single commitId in the commitlists. It worked fine. Check above update.

Comment: Hi @TejaswiniN Did you check out above update. How did it go?